# echo elements of an stdclass object

Tags: php, stdclass, surveymonkey

we're working with an api to pull data from a particular web based survey site, we need to individually access (for storing in a db) or even just echo the EmailAddress component in the object. The object we have is :

```
object(stdClass)[1]
    public 'Results' => 
        array (size=1)0 => 
            object(stdClass)[3]
                public 'EmailAddress' => string 'testemail@test.net' (length=28)
                public 'ListID' => string '947812747189789asf789a7' (length=32)
                public 'ResultsOrderedBy' => string 'email' (length=5)
                public 'OrderDirection' => string 'asc' (length=3)
                public 'PageNumber' => int 1
                public 'PageSize' => int 50
                public 'RecordsOnThisPage' => int 1
                public 'TotalNumberOfRecords' => int 1
                public 'NumberOfPages' => int 1
```

All we need to do is access/echo the EmailAddress element. Have found similar questions on stack but answers dont seem to apply in this case : have tried

```
echo $result->Results[0]->EmailAddress;
```

and

```
echo $result->Results->EmailAddress;
```

without any luck

thanks!

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: PS stdClass is an object not array, Array indexes are accessed by [] while object properties are accessed by ->

Comment: please put echo "<pre>"; and print_r and show me your results

Answer (score 0):

**$result->Results[0]->EmailAddress** seemed to be workable!

However try access them piece by piece,

```
var_dump($result);
var_dump($result->Results);
var_dump($result->Results[0]);
var_dump($result->Results[0]->EmailAddress);
```

Answer (score 0):

loop Results first using foreach then find email address with the key define something like this

```
foreach ( $result->Results as $key=>$rows ): 
      echo $rows->Email_address; 
endforeach;
```